# GAE Whitelist IP VPC tied to App Engine secondary instance not working firewall

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, whitelist, vpc

I read into this article:
[How to properly configure VPC firewall for App Engine instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442545/how-to-properly-configure-vpc-firewall-for-app-engine-instances)
This was a huge help in getting the firewall setup in the first place - so for those who have found this and are struggling with that - follow along.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-shared-vpc is a good reference, as there are some accounts that need permissions "added" to make the magic happen.

My issue - I have two containerized services running in AppEngine one default (website), one API.  I've configured the API to run in a VPC/subnet separate from the default created one.  I have not made any changes to the firewall settings directly hanging off the App Engine settings as those are global, and do not let you target a specific instance - and the website needs to remain public, while the API should require whitelisting access.

**dispatch.yaml** for configuring subdomain mapping

```
dispatch:
  - url: "www.example.com/*"
    service: default

  - url: "api.example.com/*"
    service: api
```

**API yaml settings**:

```
network:
  name: projects/mycool-12345-project/global/networks/apis
  subnetwork_name: apis
  instance_tag: myapi
```

**Create a VPC network**

```
  name - apis
  subnet name - apis
  creation mode - automatic
  routing mode - regional
  dns policy - none
  max MTU - 1460
```

**Add firewall rules**

```
  allow 130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16   port 10402,8443   tag aef-instance  priority 1000
  deny 0.0.0.0/0                        port 8443         tag myapi         priority 900
  allow 130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16   port 8443         tag myapi         priority 800
```

this works - but I cannot specify the "white list IP".

if I do the following and disable the "allow 130 / 35 networks 8443/800"

```
  allow my.ip.number.ihave   port 8443     tag myapi     priority 800
```

it never trips this rule, it never recognizes my IP.

what change / how do you configure the firewall in the VPC so it receives the public IP.  When I reviewed the logs, it said it denied my request because my IP address was 35.x.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to contact GCP support in that case. If I'm not wrong, you can directly whitelist the IP addresses at App Engine level, but it's not a standard procedure